# loading content ajax into html popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So I'm trying to make this thing with the IMDb API. When you press the film title, it's supposed to show a popup with some information about that movie. I've been doing some things, but I don't know how to continue.
How do I send the movie data I retrieved into the HTML popup I created?

So, this is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Plugin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>

</head>
<body>

<h1>...</h1>

<div id="container">

    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        <span class="movie" onclick="window.open('js/popup.js', 'imdbData','width=700,height=200');">The Shawshank Redemption </span>
        sed metus tortor, condimentum at mi non, scelerisque bibendum ante.
        Suspendisse dictum eget turpis nec condimentum. 
        fermentum mauris.
    </p>

</div>


</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

My PHP file looks like this:

```
<?php

$jsonText = file_get_contents('http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt0111161');

$imdb = json_decode($jsonText, true);


$results[] = [
    'Title' => $imdb['Title'], 'Year' => $imdb['Year'], 'imdbRating' => $imdb['imdbRating']
];

echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

And finally my main.js: (which isn't much really)

```
function getJson() {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'imdb.php',
        success: 
    });
}
```

Comment: success on $.ajax would be a function where you'll get the data and do something with it. something like ... success: function(data){console.debug(data); $("#your-popup-id").html(...)} .... where on .html you can put your data after parsing it on the success function (e.g. create a string with the html markup that uses the data), or you find specific fields on your popup and put specific pieces of data on them.

Comment: Where is the popup? on another URL?

Comment: @LShetty My file called 'popup.js' is empty, that's why I didn't post it.

Comment: `.js` is your popup file? then it should not have `.js` extn? as I asked earlier, is that another page or an element that you have within the same page that's shown when the data is populated?

Comment: @LShetty It's another page. I didn't know how to do if differently.

Comment: You're then better of to do your `ajax` stuff in the popup page.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the "popup" is, but let's assume that this "popup" has an element with id "movie-title" that you wish to populate with the `Title` property from your data:

```
function getJson() {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'imdb.php',
        success: function (data) {
             $('#movie-title').html(data.Title)
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Well, you can find my popup code in my html. I gave it a class name 'movie'. I have never used popup windows before, so I didn't really know what method to use.

Comment: Ah, so what you are trying to use is a new window. In which case, using ajax to display content in the new window doesn't make any sense. You are better off pointing your "popup" to the PHP page and displaying HTML there instead of JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I will do it in diffrent way.
First of all i'll prepare  all popup in php file (it is easer for me).
Then create popup div .e.g. id my_popup

```
function show_popup() {
$.ajax({
    dataType: "html",
    url: 'imdb.php',
    .done(function( msg ) {
```

$("#my_popup").html(msg)
    });

});

}